# Posso fazer crosspost entre o SO em Inglês e o SO em Português?

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq

Um de nosso colegas realizou um crosspost (o ato de postar a mesma pergunta em sites diferentes) em outros sites isso não é permitido e quando descobrem eles fecham sua questão. Eu sei disso por que uma vez fiz crosspost entre SuperUser, AskUbuntu e Unix & Linux e tive minhas perguntas fechadas.

Os links para as perguntas são os seguintes:

- SO Inglês: [How does the Bittorrent Sync secret work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594302/how-does-the-bittorrent-sync-secret-work)
- SO Portugês: [Como funciona o segredo de Bittorrent Sync?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/409/como-funciona-o-segredo-de-bittorrent-sync)

Gostaria de saber se esse tipo de atitude pode ser aceita entre os dois SOs já que eles estão em linguas diferentes?

Um dos pontos/motivos que nosso colega ressaltou é que alguns usuários de nossa comunidade não fala muito bem o inglês.

Comment: Qual o motivo do crosspost não ser permitido?

Answer (score 25):

Deixe eu repetir a minha opinião aqui dos comentários no post lá: acho que entre dois idiomas é permissível, são públicos bastante diferente, e em Inglês ninguêm liga com o post em Português, como que em Português seria uma lástima enorme não ter as perguntas boas. Temos que considerar sim que uma pergunta assim pode ser aceito em um mas não no outro por causa de política diferente. Também claramente não podemos deixar aqui post exatamente como no SO em Inglês (no sentido de copiar sem traduzir).

Comment: Complementando, eu acredito que seremos mais isolados mesmo. Isso só é problema entre sites da mesma língua. Acho que o ideal é deixar claro aqui que tem a mesma pergunta (nova ou antiga) em outra língua e não informar nada no original, como foi feito no exemplo apresentado.

Comment: Então não teria problema se eu fosse a uma pergunta famosa (com bastante votos) no SO em Inglês e a postasse aqui traduzida em Português? Já que estaria fazendo isso para a para aumentar a quantidade de conteúdo de qualidade para pesquisa em Português.

Comment: @bigown Isso. Ninguém quem lê em Inglês poderia fazer algo de bom com a versão em Português...

Comment: @Zignd Acho que, se isso é material que falta em Português, é uma boa ideia mesmo. Outra coisa que poderia fazer é quando a pergunta ou uma semelhante surge aqui, ligar à resposta e escrever uma tradução. Acho que fazer isso com "preguiça" pode ser melhor, ao menos no começo, para evitar que ninguém tenha vontade para perguntar/que tenha demais perguntas que ninguém tem no momento...

Comment: @Zignd Isso está sendo discutido aqui: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/traducao-de-perguntas-e-faqs.