# Onde faço pergunta, SO em Português ou em Inglês?

Tags: debate

Sou usuário do StackOverflow há cerca de um ano, eu sei bastante inglês e sempre me virei muito bem por lá.

Adorei a iniciativa do StackOverflow em português, pois ela é uma plataforma de Perguntas e Respostas decente e que na minha opinião é muito superior à qualquer outro que conheço, pelo menos falando a nível de Brasil.

Mas e agora, quando eu tiver uma dúvida, onde devo perguntar? SO ou SO em português?

Fico dividido pois:

- o SO original está estabelecido a muito tempo e possui um número de usuários infinitamente maior que o SO Pt, logo acredito que as chances de eu conseguir uma boa resposta e em bem pouco tempo são maiores;
- ao mesmo tempo eu gostaria de contribuir com a comunidade dos meus colegas de pátria/língua que não se viram tão bem com o inglês e não podem participar do SO por conta disso.

Eu não sou do tipo perguntador, mas eu não saberia muito bem como agir quando tiver uma pergunta de programação para fazer.

Alguém possui algum outro ponto para levar em consideração na hora de decidir em qual dos dois site devo fazer a pergunta?

Comment: O fato é que é muito provável que você recebe a resposta correta em poucos minutos caso opte por fazer a pergunta em inglês, visto que a comunidade é maior e por isso mais experiente. Eles também já tem uma cultura mais consolidada de ajudar o próximo. Aqui (no Brasil) ainda tem muita gente que só pensa em ser ajudado, mas não se importa em ajudar.

Comment: @EASI não concordo com sua frase que aqui não se importam em ajudar, existem inúmeros blogs/fórums que já me ajudaram muito quando precisei. Acho que o que realmente faltava era um site de Perguntas e Respostas. Eu mesmo tento ajudar ao máximo a comunidade do SO Pt para um dia ela ser referência na área de programação, mas nem sempre tenho tanto tempo quanto gostaria.

Comment: Não sei, @Math, aqui costumo ver muita gente com medo de ser prejudicada profissionalmente ao repassar seu conhecimento. Medo de ficar para trás.

Comment: @EASI sei que existem pessoas assim, mas eu acredito que a maioria ou pelo menos um número suficiente apoiam um compartilhamento de informações. Eu particularmente enxergo isso como auto desenvolvimento de suas próprias habilidades, pois às vezes você tem tanta certeza de uma coisa e compartilhando sua informação acaba descobrindo que existe um jeito mais novo, melhor e mais prático de se fazer. As pessoas que não compartilham aos poucos vão virando ermitões, cheios de manias e usando métodos/tecnologias ultrapassadas. Eu vejo um futuro promissor do SO Pt e eu espero poder contribuir ao máximo

Comment: É isso aí @Math, espero estar errado e que haja mais pessoas bacanas que pessoas egoístas.

Comment: Eu discordo na parte do "acredito que as chances de eu conseguir uma boa resposta e em bem pouco tempo são maiores". Eu sempre que vejo uma pergunta que eu possa responder eu tenho que correr, porque se eu demorar um pouco alguém responde antes e "vence" a pergunta.

Comment: @AndréLeria o fato de uma resposta `vencer` nem sempre significa que a resposta foi a melhor possível, um novato pode simplesmente estar com pressa de aceitar uma resposta. Concordo que já me surpreendi positivamente com muitas perguntas/respostas, mas acho que ainda temos bastante espaço para evoluir. Eu confio no potencial do SO Pt e sempre que posso contribuo para a comunidade. Todas as perguntas que fiz no SO Pt eu poderia ter achado a resposta em algum outro lugar, mas eu gosto muito de ouvir o que a comunidade tem a dizer e vê-la cada vez mais forte.

Comment: Relacionada: [Posso fazer crosspost entre o SO em Inglês e o SO em Português?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125/7210)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Faça em ambos!**

De fato há uma chance maior de conseguir alguma informação lá com mais qualidade mas você se surpreenderia como já consegui respostas aqui (ainda no private beta!) que eu não consegui lá no SO. E as respostas estão vindo muito rápido também. Embora eu prefira a qualidade, e não a velocidade delas.

Se você obtém uma resposta melhor em um site, vá colocar essa informação no outro, citando o autor.

Colocando nos dois você dobra suas chances de obter melhores respostas e ajuda duas comunidades.

Veja mais em [Posso fazer crosspost entre o SO em Inglês e o SO em Português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125/posso-fazer-crosspost-entre-o-so-em-ingles-e-o-so-em-portugues)

Comment: Só pra acrescentar, quando a pergunta é feita nos dois, caso a resposta venha pelo SOEN, seria muito bom ter a resposta traduzida, como foi citado o crosspost.
Querendo ou não, vai acrescentar (e muito) no conteúdo que será fornecido na nossa língua pátria.

Comment: Perfeito! A citação da pergunta do crosspost sana qualquer dúvida que poderia restar após ler sua resposta

Comment: Abri uma [discussão no Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270047/cross-posting-between-localized-stack-overflow-versions) pra saber como proceder lá. A princípio, tá mal recebida a coisa... @Math c/c bigown

Comment: @brasofilo Deixa eles pra lá. A gente avisa do que é *cross-posting* aqui e não avisa lá :) Eles querem a regra pela regra. Não há ganho algum em proibir este tipo de Xpost. Se pode trazer conteúdo do SO p/ o SOpt, porque não poderia o Xpost? E podemos levar conteúdo para lá também (assim agrada aqueles que acham que sites em diferentes línguas pulveriza a informação). Eles não vão ficar monitorando se o conteúdo lá veio daqui. Até porque isto não vai causar problema algum para eles. Pelo contrário. P/ quem me acompanha aqui sabe que eu gosto de soluções não de regras. Regra é meio e não o fim

Comment: Pois é, também acho que não é cross-post *stricto sensu* pois são tipo universos paralelos, tem um universo SE English (don't cross-post) e tem o novo universo SO Klingon (tornando a mesma info acessível a planetas diferentes). Vou ler mais a respeito tentar sumarizar isso depois, aqui e lá. Mas minha conclusão é a mesma que a sua: avisa aqui e não avisa lá.