# Crossposting de respostas para crossposting de perguntas, como proceder?

Tags: debate, tradução, respostas

Recentemente respondi a pergunta "[Como trazer o total de cada coluna no FooterRow de um jqGrid?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8924/como-trazer-o-total-de-cada-coluna-no-footerrow)" e, pesquisando sobre o assunto, me deparei com a tradução da pergunta no SOE ([How to put data on the total “FooterRow”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332506/how-to-put-data-on-the-total-footerrow)). Esse me parece ser um caso "limpo" de *crossposting* em que o autor realmente não havia conseguido uma resposta para um problema interessante em nenhum dos sites.

Eu já havia respondido a pergunta em português e inicialmente deixei um link no SOE referenciando a resposta original... Mas prontamente me senti incomodado pensando na comunidade do SOE e acabei traduzindo minha resposta. Tenho toda a intenção de contribuir com as duas comunidades. Além do mais minha resposta foi baseada em outra resposta do SOE logo, como estou consumindo informação do SOE para contribuir com o SOPT, achei justo fazer também o inverso. No fim acabei duplicando as respostas.

Um ponto de atenção é que se eu tivesse encontrado primeiro a pergunta no SOE provavelmente seguiria uma linha de ação diferente. No SOE eu provavelmente marcaria a pergunta como duplicada, enquanto no SOPT ela é certamente uma pergunta original.

Enquanto sou 100% a favor de *crossposting* responsável de perguntas (o que parece ser o caso da pergunta), me senti um pouco perdido sobre como agir em relação as respostas...

- Devemos duplica-las / traduzi-las?
- Devemos linkar resposta de cá para lá (Como fazemos de lá para cá)?
- Votar para fechar uma pergunta no SOE e respondê-la no SOPT é considerado antiético? Ou seria uma constatação natural sobre a diferença entre o que é aceitável em cada comunidade?

---

Alguns tópicos relacionados:

- [Perguntas/respostas traduzidas devem conter link para o conteúdo original?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/25/perguntas-respostas-traduzidas-devem-conter-link-para-o-conteudo-original)
- [Onde faço pergunta, SO em Português ou em Inglês?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/735/onde-faco-pergunta-so-em-portugues-ou-em-ingles)
- [Posso fazer crosspost entre o SO em Inglês e o SO em Português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125/posso-fazer-crosspost-entre-o-so-em-ingles-e-o-so-em-portugues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Devemos duplica-las / traduzi-las?

Se existe uma pergunta duplicada em outro site, e você tem uma resposta, você está livre para traduzi-la sim. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma excelente contribuição, se você estiver disposto a fazê-la.

Lembre-se que sua reposta em português está **inacessível** para falantes da língua inglesa. Ao postar uma resposta também lá você está disseminando um conhecimento.

> Devemos linkar resposta de cá para lá (Como fazemos de lá para cá)?

Há duas situações em que isso pode ser necessário/interessante:

1. Se você não for o autor da resposta, é necessário citar a fonte corretamente, mesmo que ela esteja em outro idioma.
2. Se há **mais informações** na resposta em português que na resposta em inglês (sei lá, vai ver a resposta é longa e você ficou com preguiça de traduzir tudo...), então colocar um link para a pergunta original ajuda. Pois não só abre a possibilidade de alguém "terminar o serviço", mas mesmo de um falante do inglês somente abrir sua resposta no Google Translator e achar a informação que precisa.

   O ideal é claro é que isso não seja necessário, mas somos todos contribuidores voluntários, cada um participa na medida que quer. Uma resposta parcial pode ser mais útil que resposta nenhuma. Da mesma forma que uma resposta simples com um link para recursos externos é útil mesmo que não aborde todas as informações contidas nesse link (somente as estritamente relevantes para se responder ao que foi perguntado).

Por fim, eu seria 100% a favor dos posts do SO conterem pequenos links discretos (*unobtrusive*) para perguntas equivalentes em outros idiomas - tal como a Wikipedia faz com seus artigos. Mas como esse é um tema controverso (a própria *existência* do SOPT não é muito bem aceita por muita gente) ainda não me arrisco a abrir a boca pra sugerir...

Quem sabe quando tivermos o SOES, SORU e SOTR a funcionar plenamente eu volte no assunto. Mas por ora, eu arriscaria dizer que há bem menos interesse da comunidade do SOEN em links em português do que da nossa em links em inglês, de modo que se o link não acrescenta nada eu sugiro não fazê-lo.

> Votar para fechar uma pergunta no SOE e respondê-la no SOPT é considerado antiético? Ou seria uma constatação natural sobre a diferença entre o que é aceitável em cada comunidade?

Ambas são comunidades distintas, deve-se agir conforme os limites de cada uma. Se um assunto é on-topic numa delas e off-topic na outra, responder uma e fechar a outra é a ação correta de fato. No caso, a dúvida é somente se a pergunta é duplicada ou não, certo?

Nesse caso você pode até mesmo fazer as duas coisas: responder (focando no caso específico do autor) e votar para fechar. Não é "errado" responder algo que se sabe que será fechado, já fiz isso algumas vezes, apenas para ajudar o autor (e sempre com pressa, pra postar antes que a pergunta fosse fechada de vez rsrs). Em geral sua resposta será ignorada pelos demais ou, em casos raros, votada a favor ou contra (tem gente que acha que tem que punir quem responde perguntas inadequadas), mas o autor certamente vai vê-la e pode se beneficiar com ela, se for esse o seu objetivo então vá em frente!

P.S. Li sua resposta e as demais na pergunta linkada, e embora veja que a pergunta possa ser duplicada a resposta não parece ser. Nesse caso faz ainda mais sentido responder **e** fechar, pois as duas postagens podem ser mescladas e sua resposta ser incluída na mesclagem.

Comment: Eu estava escrevendo uma resposta, mas você foi mais rápido e deixou a minha obsoleta :) Sobre o que fazer com a resposta no caso de perguntas duplicadas no SO, tem mais uma opção: postar a resposta na pergunta que tiver sido linkada como a "original" da duplicata (contanto que ela faça sentido ali, o que nem sempre é o caso). E concordo com o que você diz sobre responder e votar para fechar. Eu às vezes faço isso também, mas tem mesmo gente que enxerga com maus olhos. Sobre incluir link para a resposta em pt, sou a favor.  [continua...]

Comment: Mesmo se você é o autor e não seja obrigado a fazer isso, acho interessante incluir algo curto, como `based on [this answer in Portuguese][link]`. É positivo para a nossa comunidade, inclusive para ajudar a combater o preconceito de que só em inglês existe conteúdo de qualidade sobre programação. E sobre sua tímida proposta de links para perguntas equivalentes em outros idiomas, também acho positivo, porém muito complicado na prática. Se já é difícil localizar e selecionar boas duplicatas em um só idioma, imagine em vários!

Comment: Acho extremamente cômico o caso de alguém, que 8 meses atrás, foi no [a51] e ficou [***perturbado** ao ver as variantes linguísticas do SO*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194959/do-the-benefits-of-having-so-in-multiple-languages-outweigh-the-risks-involved?lq=1) e pergunta sobre os ***riscos envolvidos*** :) Tirando o risco de "disseminar conhecimento", como tão bem exposto aqui, não consigo ver nenhum outro.

Comment: Eu estou com o @bfavaretto sobre os links. Acho que eles geram tráfego e interesse sobre o site (já vi vários casos de estrangeiros com conhecimento sobre mainframes, etc, respondendo no Stack Overflow em Português). Quanto ao sentimento de ameaça, muitas vezes o sentimento partiu dos próprios brasileiros e outros lusófonos. Acho que já está claro que as principais preocupações (fragmentação da comunidade original / inabilidade de manter uma comunidade em outra língua com a mesma qualidade da original) não tem fundamento

Comment: Enquanto me dediquei quase que exclusivamente ao SOPT durante os primeiros meses, agora que o area51 está mostrando indicadores saudáveis e a comunidade cresceu, voltei a dividir meu tempo livre de forma mais equilibrada entre as duas comunidades; acredito que a maior parte dos usuários mais experientes vai seguir o mesmo caminho (nunca fui um colaborar excepcional em termos quantitativos, mas procurei fazer contribuições de qualidade nos últimos quatro anos). Acho que com o tempo o medo do bicho papão vai embora, bem como as barreiras entre as comunidades.