# Há de fato um modo pessimista de ver as respostas traduzidas do SOen?

Tags: debate, suporte, respostas, votos

Percebi que muito das vezes as perguntas feitas no site não tem duplicidades, mas tem a resposta no SOen, visto que os usuários principalmente os iniciantes não dão importância em realizar pesquisas e talvez a falta de conhecimento da plataforma em inglês, ou por não saber inglês, acabam por não encontrar resposta para a maioria dos problemas enfrentados, salvo as particularidades de cada código, então publicam as perguntas e boa parte das minhas colaborações copio as respostas de outro idioma e traduzo para o pt_BR e adequo o nome de variáveis, os comentários dos códigos e até mesmo os comentários de quem respondeu, mas tenho percebido também que não tem sido bem aceita tanto em upvotos.

A pergunta que faço não é por falta de receber upvotos nas respostas traduzidas, mas parece que não são bem vistas pela comunidade, mas o que tenho feito dentro do meu limite de conhecimento foi apenas ajudar outros usuários.

Comment: Eu acredito que o meta já tenha bastante discussão à respeito. Não estou com tempo de achar os links todos agora, mas segue um ponto de partida https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1072/70 - Por acaso, um dos posts mais votados do site é uma tradução que eu fiz (com um pouco de adaptação e os devidos créditos e link para original, importante frisar isso)

Comment: Olhei várias respostas suas e não tem uma citação que tenha copiado e traduzido respostas do SOwn. Então se realmente o fez, e não citou as fontes, sim, isto é mal visto, está fora das regras e o conteúdo pode ser considerado plágio. Só pode usar conteúdo de terceiros quando a licença dele permite dentro das regras aceitas pelo autor/local, portanto vindo do SOen precisa citar a fonte. A maioria tem uma frase e o código, o que não caracteriza uma boa resposta, algumas pessoas até negativam respostas assim.

Comment: @Maniero de fato não fiz referências, estou lendo aos poucos o que posso a respeito das melhores práticas da SO, não sou tão novo em SO, mas não tão ativo para ter explorado tudo o que fosse preciso para colaborar, mas agora estou ativo com frequência e quero ajudar, sobre o plágio foi sem intenção alguma de prejudicar alguém, e não acontecerá novamente.

Comment: @EliseuB. ok, então conserte o que já fez. Talvez as pessoas até darão mais valor.

Comment: @Maniero na medida do possível vou fazer sim, obrigado.

Comment: @EliseuB. Há uma pergunta sobre isso: [O que você pensa sobre a tradução de perguntas do Stack Overflow em Inglês?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7637/5878). Que tal contribuir com a sua opinião lá?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss comecei a ler os artigos relacionados desde que publiquei a dúvida, também conferi o que pensam os membros de SOen, e li também o link que você compartilhou, e agradeço por isso, tive uma noção grandiosa sobre o que todos tem a dizer de acordo com o que é melhor para a comunidade, depois até senti vergonha da minha publicação (rs) por não ter sido clara e precisa na coerência, agradeço a todos e vou me policiar sempre que puder interagir com a comunidade.

Answer (score 5):

Eu ia postar isso como comentário mas estava crescendo de mais então vai aqui mesmo. E talvez seja mais uma dica do que propriamente uma resposta 100% dentro do tópico.

Acredito que nós aprendemos muito com os outros, eu mesmo já aprendi muito aqui com perguntas e respostas dos colegas, e usei esse conhecimento para amadurecer minhas ideias e criar minhas próprias opiniões e jeito de pensar. É com essa base que eu tento responder os assuntos que eu domino. Os assuntos que eu não domino completamente eu busco fontes concretas para me apoiar, então sempre cito a fonte, link, etc, mas nunca deixo de dar o meu ponto de vista e opinião.

Com o tempo, e se vc estiver fazendo tudo direito, em breve vc vai conseguir caminhar com as próprias pernas, e nem vai precisar fazer pesquisa para responder algumas coisas, pois vc já terá o seu conhecimento adquirido. Isso vai te ajudar a responder as perguntas com as suas próprias palavras.

Outro ponto é que, mesmo nas respostas do SOen, costumam ter algum link de referência, artigo, documentação, etc. O pessoal que responde lá muitas vezes tb consultam sites externos, e vc tb pode consultar esses mesmos sites. Assim vc não vai traduzis uma resposta alheia, vc vai traduzir a documentação, e vai dar a sua própria opinião. Pense nisso, tente beber da fonte limpa, interpretar as coisas por conta própria... Isso é mais uma dica ok, não é uma crítica ou puxão de orelha, mas acho que é uma coisa que pode te ajudar a crescer sozinho.

Agora se isso é mal visto pela comunidade não posso afirmar, eu tenho várias respostas aqui que busquei recursos externos, mesmo quando consulto o SOen tento apenas usa-lo como um "start" para escrever algo, e mesmo que eu uso a solução de lá eu nunca deixo de citar fontes, incluir uma imagem extra, e enriquecer o conteúdo de alguma forma com algo a mais. Inclusive de tanto "beber da água limpa" tenho consultado cada vez menos o SOen para responder qq coisa, até pq, quem responde lá tb teve que consultar em algum lugar como eu disse anteriormente, e eu tento consultar nos mesmos lugares que eles, e não na resposta deles ;)

[]´s

Comment: não levei como bronca, levei todas as orientações como forma de crescimento e foi esse o motivo que publiquei a pergunta, pois é um pouco responsa fazer uma pergunta no meta, estou mais consciente de como e porque ajudar e vou fazer o que posso para ajudar as pessoas tendo como "start" essa organização. Grato!