# Post de perguntas já feitas no stack overflow inglês

Tags: debate

Boa tarde a todos. Gostaria de saber se é permitido postar perguntas aqui no so brasileiro que já foram postadas no americano. Trago essa pergunta pois muitas vezes posto aqui e não obtenho respostas satisfatórias e acabo tendo que recorrer ao so americano. Porém, as vezes, nem lá obtenho as respostas que preciso. Sendo assim posto a mesma pergunta aqui no so brasileiro. O problema é que dá muito trabalho traduzir todo o problema e eu acharia mais fácil apenas deixar o link da pergunta feita no so americano aqui. Isso é permitido? Há regras a respeito disso?

Comment: não existem problema em postar perguntas que já existam lá aqui no SOpt, porém só o link não basta, vc tem q refazer a pergunta por completo aqui, até pq são sites diferentes e idiomas diferentes.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/125/101